# [rospack] Error: package 'map_server' not found

Tags: navigation, mapping, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have used gmapping to build a map ,then I want to save the map: rosrun map_server map_saver .  it prints: "`[rospack] Error: package 'map_server' not found`".   Can someone help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233257/%5Brospack%5D-error:-package-%27map_server%27-not-found/) by [wang cong](https://answers.ros.org/users/26684/wang-cong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2016-04-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sounds like you have to run

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-map-server
```

(assuming you're using ROS Indigo). If that doesn't help, there might indeed be a problem with your path setup and @TomSon's advice applies.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wang cong](https://answers.ros.org/users/26684/wang-cong/) on 2016-05-02**:
thanks.I used to run `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-map-server`, but it prints: `ros-indigo-map-server :Depends: libsdl-image1.2-dev but it is not going to be installed`.I don't know how to do next?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2016-05-02**:
This means you likely have some sort of package install/version conflict that normally does not appear on a clean Ubuntu install. Either google for "is not going to be installed" and learn how to resolve this, or perform a fresh install of Ubuntu.

**Comment by [wang cong](https://answers.ros.org/users/26684/wang-cong/) on 2016-05-02**:
Thanks. I use `sudo aptitude install libsdl-image1.2-dev`,and it works....Although I don't know why.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2016-05-02**:
Ok, normally dependencies like this should be installed automatically, so there might still be an issue lingering. But you can probably ignore that for now :)

**Comment by [wang cong](https://answers.ros.org/users/26684/wang-cong/) on 2016-05-02**:
I am learning linux and ROS  a little time ,so there maybe some problems.Thanks again

**Comment by [quannv](https://answers.ros.org/users/34454/quannv/) on 2018-04-02**:
I tried to run `sudo aptitude install libsdl-image1.2-dev` and remove installed version, then re-install. It works ok

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**add this lines to your .bashrc**

source /opt/ros//setup.bash

export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home//catkin_ws:/opt/ros//share:/opt/ros//stacks

export ROS_WORKSPACE=/home//catkin_ws

***for example***

source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash

export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/bgs/catkin_ws:/opt/ros/kinetic/share:/opt/ros/kinetic/stacks

export ROS_WORKSPACE=/home/bgs/catkin_ws

---

Originally posted by [Gayan Brahmanage](https://answers.ros.org/users/26769/gayan-brahmanage/) with karma: 929 on 2017-05-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1